# Focus/Trigger/Click on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am implementing one algorithm, and to make it done I need a js code that I can write in browser console, and this calendar to get focus/clicked/triggered, so the calendar will open and new html elements like dates and others will appear. 
I'm talking about : https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#default
I tried in console things like `$('#datepicker').focus() or trigger('click') or click()` but it doesn't work :(

Comment: can you provide your algorithm?

Comment: It will make all much-more complicated. I need to work with HTML of this datepicker. The HMTL appears only after input is focused or clicked. I can't achieve this events with js/jquery code. It is possible to write smth in browser console and in result to get an input focused or clicked?

Comment: Nope. The HTML of values,dates and so on is rendered on the page just after input was clicked/focused, and interface of calendar is appeared

Comment: open the link from question. Example of enter data. Open source code and inspect the code before the input was clicked. It was no more html after. But once you click on input, it appears much-more new HTML. What I'm trying is to make a automatizated-bot that enter on the page where this type of calendar exists, trigger a click on the input, and then innerHTML some values to make right calculations for me.

Comment: Lol, it's not a spam bot. I made a financial API that collects data from all user debit cards and tranzactions. So, on the bank page which don't have API, I make a bot that will put this starting-ending date values to query the database for user's tranzactions